# What is socket type?

Tags: c, sockets

Whether you use winsock or posix the function you use to create network socket requires you to specify address family, protocol and 'type' of the socket. Yet it seems this parameter has very little significance to the programmer and it can also be determined by looking at the other two parameters. So what's the deal here? Is there some historical reason? Like did vikings use this parameter to lure the english out of their castles?

Comment: There are many types of "sockets", not only TCP or UDP sockets. Some of them use the third argument to the `socket` call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you please give an example of various protocols being used with multiple sock types and point out the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [udplite](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udplite.7.html) protocol, for example, the socket is created like this:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDPLITE);
```

[SCTP](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sctp.7.html) sockets:

```
sctp_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
sctp_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

---

In other words, the third argument to `socket` calls is not always derived from the first two.

Comment: O-kay.. Are there any other values for type you could use in this example?

Comment: @Pyjong Added more examples for you.

Comment: FYI another important example: 
With `AF_UNIX`, the `protocol` argument is not used. But the `type` argument specifies the semantics: `SOCK_DGRAM`, `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_SEQPACKET`.

Comment: @GilHamilton It requires that argument to be 0, does it not?

Comment: Actually no (at least not on Linux -- it can also be `PF_UNIX`). But yes, of course the language binding for C requires the argument to actually be present, and the kernel function does verify that it matches one of those values. However, my point was just to give an additional frequently-used example where the `domain` and `protocol` arguments cannot be used to determine the `type` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to agree with you that the `type` argument is mostly redundant (though I haven't looked through the [full list of internet protocols](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml), I may be missing some special cases) except for one important case: raw sockets (`SOCK_RAW`). Those do not really have a protocol associated with them, so it wouldn't make sense to put that information in the `protocol` argument.

Comment: Thank you, SOCK_RAW definitely is worth examining. But I think you can forget about the list of protocols though. Only few chosen ones are useable. There is an interesting paragraph here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html ctrl+f "The protocol specifies" if you're interested of course.

Comment: Ok that came out wrong. I should have said "only few are usable as a parameter to this particular function". Thanks you got me on the right path.